# Is there a method to stop a player when I stop touching a virtual joystick?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and I'm trying to make an isometric 3d game, but I have some problem, I would like that the player stops moving when I stop using the virtual joystick. Here's my 2 scripts for movement. The first one is in the virtual joystick to make it move and the second one is in the player and make it move in the direction of the joystick.

Joystick script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

public class VirtualJoystick : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{

private Image bgImg;
private Image joystickImg;
private Vector3 inputVector;

private void Start()
{
    bgImg = GetComponent<Image>();
    joystickImg = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>();
}

public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData ped)
{
    Vector2 pos;
    if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(bgImg.rectTransform, ped.position, ped.pressEventCamera, out pos))
    {
        pos.x = (pos.x / bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
        pos.y = (pos.y / bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);

        inputVector = new Vector3(pos.x * 2 + 1, 0, pos.y * 2 - 1);
        inputVector = (inputVector.magnitude > 1.0f) ? inputVector.normalized : inputVector;

        // Move joystickImg
        joystickImg.rectTransform.anchoredPosition =
            new Vector3(inputVector.x * bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 3
                , inputVector.z * (bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / 3));

    }
}

public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData ped)
{
    OnDrag(ped);
}

public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData ped)
{
    inputVector = Vector3.zero;
    joystickImg.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector3.zero;
}

public float Horizontal()
{
    if (inputVector.x != 0)
        return inputVector.x;
    else
        return Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
}

public float Vertical()
{
    if (inputVector.x != 0)
        return inputVector.z;
    else
        return Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
}
}
```

Player Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
public float moveSpeed = 20f;
public VirtualJoystick moveJoystick;

private void Update()
{
    Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;

    dir.x = moveJoystick.Horizontal();
    dir.z = moveJoystick.Vertical();

    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(dir * moveSpeed);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For stopping the player when you let go of the virtual joystick, we can tell the player's rigidbody to sleep. This will make the player halt until another force is added to it.

Update your Player script to the following:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 20f;
    public VirtualJoystick moveJoystick;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    private Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;
    private bool wasMoving = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        dir.x = moveJoystick.Horizontal();
        dir.z = moveJoystick.Vertical();

        if (dir.magnitude > 0)
        {
            wasMoving = true;
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (wasMoving && dir.magnitude == 0f)
        {
            wasMoving = false;
            rb.Sleep();
        }

        rb.AddForce(dir * moveSpeed);
    }

}
```

It's also a good idea to store the `Rigidbody` as a variable so you don't recompute it every update. Be sure to drag it into the script from the inspector.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it doesn't change anything, again it move and keep moving when I release the joystick

Comment: I think it should be something like: it takes the coordinates and when I stop touching joystick it moves the player to those coordinates

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by you want the player to stop moving? Do you want them to freeze in place? I have edited my answer to say the player will still be affected by gravity and will fall straight down after the joystick is no longer moved.

Comment: Sure, I mean that when I'm using the joystick I want that the player moves, and that when I stop using it, the player stay in his position, but for now it keeps moving. Image a ball, you spin it in a plane by touching a button, and when release, the ball keeps rotate... that's "normal", but I want that the ball stops immediatly in his position. If it can help you can serch the game brawl stars on youtube to understand what I mean

Comment: I tried new version script and still the same result, the ball keeps moving even when I stop using joystick

Comment: In almost every game where there's a virtual joystick when you stop using it the player stops moving. I really hope I have been quite explicit

Comment: Oh this is a top-down game? My apologies, I was under the impression it was a side-scroller. I can work on an updated solution soon.

Comment: @MarcoSajeva I have updated the code. It should now work for your game.